# Best practice for submit buttons

Tags: html, css, forms, input

I am hoping to get some opinions on what you think best practice is for coding form submit buttons. I'm building a new site and am thinking about changing. Here are what I see as the options:

1. `input type="submit"` with a background image, and CSS to hide the value text - this is what I currently use.
2. `input type="image"` with `src="source.jpg"` - I understand I don't need to then hide the value text, but I have always preferred to have the image in a central place in the CSS, so if I need to change it I can do so easily. Due to SEO reasons, however, I am trying to avoid hiding text.
3. `button` - I've actually never used this, but w3 says "If you use the  element in an HTML form, different browsers may submit different values. Use  to create buttons in an HTML form." - why would you use this?

Any thoughts appreciated :)

Comment: Especially when asked without specifying context, criteria, and specific requirements, the question is non-constructive. There are also odd assumptions, like the relevance of button texts in SEO, and a reference to “w3”, with a quotation that looks w3schools-style.

Comment: This is for submit buttons on contact forms, or help-request forms. Re SEO, I didn't say the button text was relevant, I said I was trying to avoid 'hiding text' with CSS, which Google has said they frown upon. Apologies, by "w3" I meant "w3schools".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I think it's best to keep controls natural. It allows the browser/OS to determine how they should look, and the typical result is that the user is more comfortable with controls they already know.

So, I use `<input type="submit"/>` for a submit button, `<input type="image"/>` to get the coordinates of a click on an image (useful for my game where you might click on a map to travel), and `<button>` for JavaScript-powered buttons that aren't related to the form itself (such as a Preview button). It's all about using the right tools for the job, and keeping things familiar for the users.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not an option for me (on any of the sites I currently work with, anyway) to leave the submit buttons natural, they need to be styled. Thanks for the input, though! Makes sense :)

Answer (score 3):

Go with the default

```
<input type="submit" value="mysubmit"  class="button" />
input.button {
    background-image: url(/images/buttons/add.png); /* 16px x 16px */
    background-color: transparent;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;        /* make the cursor like hovering over an <a> element */
    height: 16px;
    padding-left: 16px;     /* make text start to the right of the image */
    vertical-align: middle; /* align the text vertically centered */
}
```

Comment: And can you tell me why you use type=submit rather than type=image?